# Output as zero in data frame with size() in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a file that consists of three columns: A, B and C with some integer. Using python, Let say I would like to `grouby()` column 'A' and get the `size()` of each group with number greater than 4 , 6 and 8 in column 'B'. So I implemented the code below:

```
    >>> import pandas as pd
    >>> 
    >>> df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\t")
    >>> df
       A  B   C
    0  1  4   3
    1  1  5   4
    2  1  2  10
    3  2  7   2
    4  2  4   4
    5  2  6   6
    >>> 
    >>> out1 = df[df['B'] > 4].groupby(['A']).size().reset_index()
    >>> out1
       A  0
    0  1  1
    1  2  2
    >>> out2 = df[df['B'] > 6].groupby(['A']).size().reset_index()
    >>> out2
       A  0
    0  2  1
    >>> out3 = df[df['B'] > 8].groupby(['A']).size().reset_index()
    >>> out3
    Empty DataFrame
    Columns: [A, 0]
    Index: []
    >>>
```

`out1` is the output that I want. But for `out2` and `out3`, how do I get the data frame similar to `out1` with zero as below?

```
out2:
   A  0
0  2  1
1  2  0

out3:
   A  0
0  2  0
1  2  0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is create boolean mask, convert to integers and aggregate `sum` - here is necessary grouping by `Series` like `df['A']` instead by column name `A`:

```
out3 = (df['B'] > 8).astype(int).groupby(df['A']).sum().reset_index()
#alternative
#out3 = (df['B'] > 8).view('i1').groupby(df['A']).sum().reset_index()
print (out3)
   A  B
0  1  0
1  2  0
```

Another idea is create helper column - e.g. assign `B` to new values and then aggregate `sum`:

```
out3 = df.assign(B = (df['B'] > 8).astype(int)).groupby('A')['B'].sum().reset_index()
print (out3)
   A  B
0  1  0
1  2  0
```